# limit max length of mail address with regex + c#

Tags: c#, regex

I create a regex to validate email address  this is my regex:

```
@"^\w+(\.?[-+\w])*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,80}$"
```

I would like that the max length of the mail address is 80 but with this regex i only limit the last part of the mail after the **.**

Now

```
aaa@aa.ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff is invalid
```

but

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@aa.ffffffff is valid
```

How can i do this?

Comment: You can't, regex is not the right tool. What about string.Length?

Comment: This validation is a 2-steps process. One that validates the format and one that validates the length. For the length you might use a regular expression, but there are better ways, as suggested by @peer.

Comment: Why don't you split them and compare the length of each string?

Comment: I prefer edit only the regex to avoid to have a new build and deployement (the regex is in the database)

Comment: @user1428798 sometimes, you need to change the code; edit: no, let's be honest - ***most***-times, you need to change the code

Answer (score 1):

You can validate within two steps.Just try it out.

```
   Regex validCharsRegex = new Regex(@"^[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+(\.[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+)*" +
                                                      "@" + @"((([\-\w]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))$");
   Match match = validCharsRegex.Match(stringText.Trim());
   if (match.Success && stringText.Length <=80 )
   {
     // You logic here
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I made an obvious mistake, but I've made a test with a [conditional expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) with *Yes* and *No* clause. The test condition is the email format validation:

```
(?:^\w+\.?[-+\w]*@\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$)
```

If the condition is met, search the input for any character between 6 (the minimum length - *x@x.xx*) and 80 repetitions:

```
^.{6,80}$
```

If the condition is not met, search again for the expression in the test condition (which produces no result):

```
^\w+\.?[-+\w]*@\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$
```

The whole regex looks like this:

```
(?(?:^\w+\.?[-+\w]*@\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$)^.{6,80}$|^\w+\.?[-+\w]*@\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$)
```

And it *seems* it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You can check sthe String.Lenght property to validate. If you wanna check the parts before and after the " @ " character, you can do a string.Split on character @ , and check the lenght of the 2 string resulting from the operation